# SignalR: How to disconnect clients from server?

Tags: c#, signalr, signalr-hub

We currently have a Web Application, a SignalR Server and a RabbitMQ Server. The Web application receives events from SignalR based on the events received via RabbitMQ. Our Web Application has a fallback which, in case the connection to SignalR closes and can't be established, has a polling mechanism to try to keep the data updated.

The problem: If, instead of the SignalR server, the RabbitMQ is having issues, then, from the perspective of teh WebApplication it is still connected to SignalR server, which prevents it from polling data.

The possible solution: On the event of the RabbitMQ Server has issues connecting to SignalR, we would like to the SignalR server to actively refuse connections on a specified Hub and terminate all the connections it has.

Based on that i tried the following approach (inside the specified Hub), but no success:

```
public async override Task OnConnectedAsync()
        {
            var feature = Context.Features.Get<IConnectionHeartbeatFeature>();
            feature.OnHeartbeat(state =>
            {
                try
                {
                    if (rabbitMQWorker.IsConnected == false)
                        Context.Abort();
                }
                catch
                {

                }
            }, Context.ConnectionId);

            await base.OnConnectedAsync();
        }
```

Even if it worked, I would still need to refuse any connections. Is this something feasable or am I heading towards the wrong direction?